# 2d animation rendering crops the sceene

Tags: rendering

I am using blender to make an animation in 2d: a couple of arrows move over an image to explain something. However when I render the animation 900x728 it shows a different cut than the original image which is also 900 x 728.
This does not happen in avi raw, but that file will also show the cropping when opened in a video editor. What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Are the render settings dimensions the same as those of the original image? Is your resolution set at 100%? Are you using the compositor, and if so, what is your node tree like?

Comment: Yes, yes and no I am not using the compositor (just watched a video just to understand what it is) and figured out that there are no nodes in my file.

Comment: In order to better help you it might be easier if you upload your file. You can use: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it, here the file   [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1199" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1199/)

Comment: Meanwhile I played around with the orthographic scale, which seems to influence the matter, but I can not predict its behavior too wel.